# Why do I get a Oauth error with http://www.website.com, but not http://website.com

Tags: drupal, oauth

I have a Drupal based site that has the Twitter module installed, and when users log in using their Twitter account from http://www.website.com, they get a "Invalid Twitter Oauth Request", but when they do it from the http://website.com, it works fine. Any ideas on what the cause could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an educated guess but you have probably specified the callback to be `http://website.com/callback/` regardless of the originating subdomain.

Chances are that once the callback is invoked, necessary request token data stored in a cookie is not accessible in the other subdomain.

If this is the case there are two solutions:

1. Try to make sure that the callback is set dynamically in the request token request to match the current subdomain. You do that by submitting the `oauth_callback` parameter, or
2. Make sure that your cookies are valid across `*.website.com`.